# How to merge two JSON objects?

Tags: java, json

I have two json objects

```
JsonObject taJson = Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add(JSON_NAME, ta.getName()).build();
JsonObject taJsontwo = Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add(JSON_EMAIL, ta.getEmail()).build();
array.add(taJson);
array.add(taJsontwo);
```

This creates two seperate json objects, one for the name and one for the email. I just need one object both with the name and email. I'm not very well versed in json or javafx so I was trying things like

```
JsonObject taJson = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add(JSON_NAME, ta.getName()).build();
taJson.add(JSON_EMAIL, ta.getEmail()).build();
```

and

```
JsonObject taJson = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add(JSON_NAME, ta.getName()).build();
JsonObject taJson = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add(JSON_EMAIL, ta.getEmail()).build();
```

But neither of these work.

Comment: Is your problem that you have two `JsonObject`s as input or do you want to create one with two properties and you just do not know how?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
JsonObject taJson = Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add(JSON_NAME, ta.getName()).build();
JsonObject taJsontwo = Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add(JSON_EMAIL, ta.getEmail()).build();
JSONObject combined = new JSONObject();
combined.put("name", taJson);
combined.put("email", taJsontwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating two objects, add it to the builder like the code below:

```
JsonObjectBuilder builder = Json.createObjectBuilder().add(JSON_NAME, ta.getName());
builder.add(JSON_EMAIL, ta.getEmail());
```

And when done building, create the object as below:

```
JsonObect taJson = builder.build();
```